# angular2: property binding not found

Tags: angular

I'm getting this message from angular2 when `component+template` is rendered:

> Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'alert'.

I've created this component:

```
interface Alert {
    type: string;
    msg: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'signin',
  styleUrls: [ './signin.style.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './signin.template.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  host: {
    class: 'signin-page app'
  }
})
export class Signin implements OnInit {

    private form:FormGroup;
    private alerts: Array<Alert>;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private commty: UsersService) {}

    ngOnInit():void {
        //...
    }

    private addAlert(message: string): void {
        this.alerts.push({type: 'danger', msg: message});
    }

    public closeAlert(index): void {
        this.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };
}
```

The related html template code is:

```
<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert(i)" dismissible="true">
    <div [innerHTML]="alert.msg"></div>
</alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

type is not default attr of html dom element(alert dom is `shadow dom`)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM

```
<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [attr.type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert(i)" dismissible="true">
    <div [innerHTML]="alert.msg"></div>
</alert>
```

Comment: Thanks @anshu .I don't quite to figure out what do you mean with your comment. I'm not a ninja using angular2. Could you explain me a bit better what you mean with `[attr.type]=`?

Comment: alert is not html element and anguler is making it 'sudo element' means element which is created by angular so attributes on these elements will work differantly. please read for more info  https://toddmotto.com/emulated-native-shadow-dom-angular-2-view-encapsulation